# how to access Session to store DataTable in class other than controller in .net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, datatable

I have a C#.NET MVC Application. I need to store the `DataTable` containing the query result for further use. I need to store it differently for each user.

I am thinking of using `Session` for it. But the problem is that `Session` is not accessible in the class in which I am getting the query result, since this class is a simple class and not a controller.

`public DataTable table = DataProvider.SelectStoreProcedure("SPSelectCRMDoctorRequest");`

I want to store this in Session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible to access the session in class

```
 var dt=HttpContext.Current.Session["sessionname"];
```